# central div moves around the website when I resize the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My central block keeps on moving to the left when I resize the browser window

normal:

http://imgur.com/b2AVkUx

after resizing browser window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmUKG.jpg

so i managed to figure out how to keep the navi and footer relatively undisruptive during resizing, but I just can't seem to figure out how to deal with the body, help please?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Line After Line</title>
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head> 

<body>
    <div id = "top">
        <div id = "opening">
            <a href = "index.html">
                <h1 id = "logo"> Line After Line </h1>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id = "navi">
            <ul>
                <li> Read </li>
                <li> Write</li>
                <li> Review </li>
                <li> Donate </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id = "updates">
        <h4>Updates</h4>
        <ul>
            <li> number one blah blah blah blah blah hahahahaahah </li>
                </br>
            <li>number two blah blah blah </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>  

    <div id = "story">
        <a href = "blockOne.html">
            <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockOne" >
                <p> Hello I this is a test block </p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockTwo"></div>
        <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockThree"></div>
        <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockFour"></div>
        <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockFive"></div>
        <div class = "storyblocks" id = "blockSix"></div>
    </div>

    <div id = "footer">
        <ul>
            <li> Home </li>
            <li> A Message From Chung</li>
            <li> Contributors </li>
            <li> About </li>
            <li> Contact </li>

        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    body{
    background-color: white;    
    }

body a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top{
    background-color: black; /*use to see div area*/
    height:75px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    padding: 5px;
}

/*div surrounding the Logo */
#opening{   
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

#logo{
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;   
    float:left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#navi{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 1100px;
    left: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;

}

#navi ul li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;

}



#updates{
    /*background-color: blue; /* use to see div area */
    color: #6D8582 ;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-left: 5%; /*100px*/
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px; 
    border-right: thick solid #6D8582;
    float: left;
    position: relative;


}

#updates h4 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

#updates ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


#story , #mainStory{
    /*border: thin solid black;*/
    /*background-color: red;*/
    float: right;
    margin-left: 27%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;/* relative*/
    width: 1145px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#mainStory {
    background-color: #F7F9FA;
    width: 1050px;
    margin-right: 4.5%;

}

#mainStory p {
    color: black;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-indent:50px;
}

#mainStory h2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.storyblocks{
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    opacity: 0.6;
}



#blockOne{  
    /*border: thick solid blue; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #2A9BB5;

}

#blockTwo{  
    /*border: thick solid green; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #17EB0C;

}

#blockThree{    
    /*border: thick solid yellow; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #F0F035;

}

#blockFour{ 
    /*border: thick solid red; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #F02E4E;

}

#blockFive{ 
    /*border: thick solid purple; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #DA41E8;

}

#blockSix{  
    /*border: thick solid green; /*delete later*/
    background-color: #FC62B2;

}



#footer {
    background-color: black;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    clear: left;
    height:34px;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%

}


#footer ul li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
```

Comment: if you think about logically it becomes so absurd. You are using right as a reference but also using visual reference with elements at left but not telling that to computer and expect computer to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a fixed width and float right. Your div with the boxes is trying to stay aligned with the right hand side of the browser window, and because you won't let it resize it moves over. Either make the width a percentage, or don't float right and have a margin left 300px

Comment: thanks for the tip! Just started actually implementing CSS and realized that a lot of the attributes cannot go together..

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a problem with responsive design. If you do not have any of items ( sidebar or content) fixed you can use precentage on both of them, like :

```
  #nav {
    width:27%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-right:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #content {
    width:70%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
```

If you have something fixed ( let say sidebar ) you have to use **css media queries** and create some "patterns" for certain intervals of resolution ( width ).

You have an example which uses precentage sizes of both sides : http://jsfiddle.net/7Qpw6/